# How to protect usage.log file from direct access?

Tags: php

I have log file that contain all users and their IP addresses,
And I just found out that I can access it directly without any restriction, also I have database.sql file with the same problem.

My website is complicated, I used .htaccess files to restrict some places in my server.
But these two files are in the main root, and It's so hard to move them outside the root.
I used this code to only restrict the access to these two files inside .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "log">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "database.sql">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But my problem is when I use this code my whole website crash!
Can anyone point out for me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is log the exact filename or the extension?

Comment: Which Apache version? Have you tried `Require all denied`? And use `<FilesMatch "\.log$">` if you do not want to exclude `logo.png`

Comment: I just found the problem, the code was working fine, but there is url mask function was making all links to not work

Comment: You can create robots.txt file in root & disallow files.

Comment: in one: `\.(sql|log)$` It's regex

Comment: Okay I got it, I will change it to this.

Comment: If you are on Apache 2.4, `Order` / `Deny` doesn't work anymore (or at least depricated). The new access control is `Require`